# Improve load time of page

Tags: jquery

I have a page with 2 sections, intro and main page.

Once page is loaded, intro is displayed and content is hidden, on click of skip intro css classes are swiped, i.e. page content is displayed and intro is hidden.

Also a variable is stored in cookie so that next time intro is not displayed to the user.

This is all working fine so far, only issue is that when i load the page it remains blank for few seconds, until javascript is executed.

Can there be a solution for this?

Page in question: http://new.brandonplanning.com/home

Script i have created: http://jsfiddle.net/alokjain_lucky/rEBfF/7/

Comment: What about adding a "Loading please wait..." text that you will hide when the JS is ready (by the way, loading is instantaneous for me).

Comment: Yes, i thought of adding a text "Loading..." that's a good alternative, but i was wondering if there is any other way possible for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can fill in a `Spinner` in the intro section by default and the javascript is loaded and executed remove that `spinner`(basically a .gif image) and load whatever you want to in the intro section